# May I use alkyd primer with acrylic paint

Tags: acrylic, alkyd

I have a fuel canister made in 1943, cleaned it from rust and old paint and sprayed over with gray primer that I had in garage. The primer is alcyd paint, with anti-corrosion properties.

Most of my spray cans seem to contain acrylic paint, can I use them over the alcyd base or should I go shopping for alcyd paint, just to be sure?

Comment: Are the topcoats from that same brand acrylic? Check it out.  It's not uncommon for primers to have a somewhat different chemistry from the topcoat.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica No, they are completely different, I applied the base using air compressor and spray gun, while the paints are in spray bottles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use acrylic over alkyd primer, in fact that is a preference of mine. What I generally do **not** do is apply alkyd finish over acrylic (unless I sand thoroughly).

Comment: I will give it a try when the base is dry. After all, it is not Bentley I'm painting, just want to learn from this.